# Creating Columns in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Please help with basic XSLT template for creating columns for each item.
INPUT XML:

```
<list>
    <item>
        <name>John</name>
        <image>John Picture</image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <image>Bob Picture</image>
    </item>
</list>
```

OUTPUT HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Bob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Picutre</td>
        <td>Bob Picture</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Have you done something for this?

Comment: Yes, I tried several things, but just didn't want to clutter the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the XSLT which you write for achive the result, below is the code you can use:

**Final Updated Script:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="item/name">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="item/image">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake :( I've just updated the output I need.

Comment: Means what generates?

Comment: Is this help you to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Sorry, no. I need to generate columns (in the beginning by mistake I made rows in output). Updated desired ouput several minutes ago. I mean - each person - separate column (not row).

Comment: Here is new link with new code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBth/29

Answer (score 0):

If you want a column for each `item` element, then you should start off by selecting the elements under only the first `item` elements, as these will represent the start of each row

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[1]/*">
```

Then, to build the row, get the relevant element under all `item` element which has the same name as the one currently selected

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../../item/*[name() = name(current())]" />
```

Although it might be easier if you define a key like so...

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="item/*" use="name()" />
```

Then you get the elements with the same name like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('items', name())" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="items" match="item/*" use="name()" />

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="item[1]/*">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('items', name())" />
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes all elements are present under each `item` (well, at least under the first `item`).

Comment: Sorry. I guess I miss something. This threw me bunch of empty TRs

Comment: I tested it out at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtq, so perhaps the XML you are using is slightly different to what is shown in your question?